# Неожиданная остановка при обработке данных

Tags: delphi, sql-server

Обновляю очень много данных в MSSQL 2008, с помощью программы написанной на Delhpi 2010. В какой то момент обновление данных прекращается, но при этом ничего не висит. Я пытаюсь обновить 30000 записей с помощью хранимой процедуры в  MSSQL. Обновление останавливается каждый раз на различной записи. В качестве решения стал скрипт вызова процедуры выводить на форму, тем самым процесс отработки обновления данных замедлился (программа стала медленнее работать из-за обновления информации на экране), при этом остановок больше не наблюдалось.
Как оптимально решить данную проблему?

MSSQL2008

Comment: Действительно странная ошибка... А вы замечали на каких записях идет остановка обновления? Может там поля неверно заполнялись или что-то вроде того.

Comment: А потоков (TThread) в Вашей программе нет?

Comment: С полями всё нормально, остановка в каждый раз на новом месте.
Потоки есть, так как использую Indy компоненты для работы с локальной сетью.

Comment: Получилось решить проблему вставкой дополнительного sleep(5) перед отработкой каждого обновления. Пусть теперь нет такой хорошей скорости вставки, зато больше не зависает )))

Comment: Чувствтую, что есть гонка. Вставка sleep, который частично решил проблему (проблема просто пока не проявляется), только подтверждает это.